# Does water amplify radio waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, water, radio-frequency

Does water really amplify radio signals? What is the energy source? Does the water cool down? Does it works for Wifi?

Is salty water better or worse as an amplifier?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE :) Please try to keep the scope of one question limited. Further - did you do any research about this?

Comment: Why do you suggest that water might amplify radio signals?  There's no reason that it should.  However, you may have some additional information that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: Are you by chance referring to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Uqf71muwWc ?

Comment: NoEigenvalue is right. I saw those videos claiming that water amplifies those signals, but I do not know if it is a scam.

Comment: If you have an antenna near salt water, you will need to take the water into account to model the radiation pattern, but that is from the water reflecting the transmission and redirecting it, not amplifying it...

Comment: @Sanya: I searched with Google, but I cannot trust the accuracy of the information found. I did an experiment with an USB Wifi dongle, a bottle of potable water and tested signal intensity with InSSIDer 4. I found no evidence of amplification, but it may not work at those frequencies, or may need salty water, or it may need.

Comment: If I use salty water between the router and the USB receiver, signal intensity goes lower. If I put the salty bottle behind the router, the signal does not amplifies, but becomes less variable. Here is a screen capture: http://i.imgur.com/ux1sIN4.jpg

Comment: @Jon Custer yes, salty water behind the router seems to stabilize the signal, but I don't know if radio reflections on the bottle help, or actually add noise to the signal (by self interference). I get a more stable intensity.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you acquire the idea that "water amplifies radio waves"? Water in its natural impure form is usually conducting and damps radio waves and the saltier the more conductive it becomes. There exists no solid, liquid or gas that amplifies radio waves (Even in a maser you have to supply energy.)